# How to create multiple instances from a template map in groovy

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, scope

For an internal status logging in my jenkins pipeline I have created a "template map which I want do use in multiple stages which are running independently in parallel

```
def status= [
    a : '',
    b: [
            b1: '',
            b2: '',
            b3: ''
      ],
    c: [ 
        c1: '',
        c2 : ''
    ]
]
```

this status template I want to pass to multiple parallel running functions/executors. Inside the parallel branches I want to modify the status independently. See the following minimal example

```
def status= [
    a : '',
    b: [
        b1: '',
        b2: '',
        b3: ''
    ],
    c: [
        c1: '',
        c2 : ''
    ]
]

def label1 = "windows"
def label2 = ''


parallel firstBranch: {
        run_node(label1, status)
    }, secondBranch: {
        run_node(label2, status)
    },
    failFast: true|false

def run_node (label, status){
    node(label) {
        status.b.b1 = env.NODE_NAME +"_"+ env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER
        sleep(1)
        echo "env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER: ${status.b.b1}"  
        // expected: env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER
        this.a_function(status)
        echo "env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER: ${status.b.b1}"  
        // expected(still): env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER (off current node)
        // is: env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info AND probably from the wrong node
    }
}

def a_function(status){
     status.b.b1 += "more Info"
     echo "env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info: ${status.b.b1}" 
     // expected: env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info
     sleep(0.5)
     echo "env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info: ${status.b.b1}" 
     // expected: env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info
}
```

Which results in

> [firstBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0
>
> [firstBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0more Info
>
> [firstBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER>more Info:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0more Info
>
> [firstBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0more Info
>
> [secondBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0more Info
>
> [secondBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0more Infomore Info
>
> [secondBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBERmore Info:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0more Infomore Info
>
> [secondBranch] env.NODE_NAME_env.EXECUTOR_NUMBER:
>   LR-Z4933-39110bdb_0more Infomore Info

Note that in the status in the first branch is overwritten by the second branch and the other way around.

How to realize independent status variables when passing thm as a parameter to functions

Comment: the jenkins pipeline is automatically generated from a config file. 
therefore it is not possible to tell in front how many instances of the status are needed. 

in a configured pipeline there might be multiple parallell nodes wit potentially multiple paralell stages each. 

this means there will be multiple clones of the status 
- one for each node that is used (in parallel) during the pipeline execution
- clones of the cloned (node) status for each stage

Answer (score 0):

You could define the template map. When you need multiple instances of the same which you may want to modify differently per instance by using cloned template map.

Here is short code snippet to show the example.

```
def template = [a: '', b: '']
def instancea = template.clone()
def instanceb = template.clone()
def instancec = template.clone()
instancea.a = 'testa'
instanceb.a = 'testb'
instancec.a = 'testc'
println instancea
println instanceb
println instancec
```

Of course, you can include bigger map, the above is only for demonstration.

Comment: is there a way to do this clone inside a function?

like 
def my_func(a){
   def new_a = a.clone()
   ...
}

Comment: or in other words is there a way to enable a function to be called multiple times in paralell without intererence of each other ?

Comment: What is the problem that you face? Use a reference variable(**newStatusMap**) of `def newStatusMap = status.clone()` inside your prallel function. If no need, do not define separate variables as above ( that was to show example only)

Comment: when adding a `def newStatusMap = status.clone()` to both branches of the parallel function and then running `run_Node(<label>, newStatusMap)` this still results in that both nodes seem to write to the same status variable

Comment: Hmm. See I believe you got the idea of how to use the template using `clone`, may be you are using it incorrectly. Just try changing from `run_node(label1, status)` to `run_node(label1, status.clone())` and see if that helps. and 'lly other call too.

Comment: that Idea I already had myself. So I tried to .clone() to all function calls but the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `status` by reference to the function. But even if you do a `status.clone()`, I suspect this isn't a deep copy of `status`. `status.b` probably still points to the same reference. You need to make a deep copy of `status` and send that deep copy to the function.

I'm not sure a deep copy of a framework map is the right way to do this. You could just send an empty map `[:]` and let the called functions add the pieces to the map that they need. If you really need to pre-define the content of the map, then I think you should add a class and create new objects from that class.

Comment: hi I converted my `status= [:]` map into a class and then call `run_Node(<label>, new status)`. This improves my issue. (I had to add Implements Serializable to my class (info from Warning).) Now I have only have the problem left how to archive the same when passing a pre-filled status class to `a_function(status)`. I already tried `status.newInstance()`but this is blocked by jenkins script approval

> method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object Approving this signature may introduce a security vulnerability! You are advised to deny it.

Comment: Because I also don't know that this is the correct solution I do not want to approve this method just by chance.
Also I tried adding Implements Clonable and then using clone() bit this doesn't work